# how to i add 3d textures to my model

Tags: modeling, texturing, texture-painting

I am trying to make a robot model. im have created the model however I need to make the body look like its a cubulation of wires. this is the texture that I want my model to be similar too

[image]

this is the model that I am making. since for me it would be to hard to turn it into wires as a modeling standpoint. since there would be too much stuff and im making this for animation/ gameplay I need a kind of 3d texture in order to make it look real and looks good. [image]

Comment: so do u mean that u want small wire like mesh projections from the model without modeling it , its called microdisplacement

Comment: you can unwrap your mesh and give it a texture of wire, you'll just need to create a normal maps from the texture so that it looks 3D

Comment: @SHikhaMittal can you explain what you mean an how it works?

Answer (score -1):

So the eventual answere to your problem is `microdisplacements`

It is a concept that if you have enough uniform geometry in your mesh , you can displace you mesh in different directions to form some interesting patters or designs , to use it , you can

**Add a plane and subdive to get upto 10k faces**

**Add a displace modifier and select add texture**

**In the texture tab (bellow materials tab)**

**open your added texture(in modifier) and change it from image to cloud(for example)**

Now your mesh has alot of bumps nd valleys , this is a simple example of micro displacements

Ususally this displacement is controlled by a image texture (in this case the cloud texture is a procedurally produced image texture) where darker areas result in deeper displacement and lighter result in higher

In your case a displacement map of wires can help , wher u can find , that can be solved by u

For more detailed informstion visit https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html